# Screw and Pulley

Tags: modifiers

I've been trying and failing at the process of making a rope for a pulley and screw, both for a Rube Goldberg Machine. What is the best way for me to make/model them so they work properly?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site. Could you add some precision to your question? Adding some images, indicating if it is for an animation or a static rendering? Or any other needed details. Thanks.

Comment: Also screenshots of what you have done so far, and what failed and why